# How to make words inside a paragraph clickable in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a line that has three buttons inside it. I know that I can use RichText with Gesture Recogniser to make them clickable like HTML `<a href="">` tag. But I am new to flutter and don't know how can I achieve that behaviour.

Also is there any better option to do similar thing?

Also I don't want to open an External Link. Just navigate to another page.

I have attached a picture containing what I want to do. [Picture of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u3A2.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';`

and the widget

```
 RichText(
        text: TextSpan(
          children: [
            TextSpan(
              text: "By Clicking Sign up you are agree to the ",
            ),
            TextSpan(
              text: "Privacy Policy ",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
              ),
              recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => print("Privacy Policy"),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: "and our "),
            TextSpan(
              text: "Terms and Conditions ",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
              ),
              recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => print("Terms and Conditions"),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: "and "),
            TextSpan(
              text: "Cookie Statement",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightGreen,
              ),
              recognizer: new TapGestureRecognizer()
                ..onTap = () => print("Cookie Statement"),
            ),
            TextSpan(text: "."),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

does it help?

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the Text widget with `GestureDetector()`

```
GestureDetector(
              child: Text(
                'Clickable text'
              ),
              onTap: () {
                //go to destination page
              },
            )
```

In case if you're opening to an external link you can check [URL launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to open websites

Comment: But I need to have it in a paragaph. For exxample,

by clicking sign up, you agreed to our <a href="link">privacy policy</a> and our <a href="link">terms and conditions</a>.